# Прозрачные StatusBar и NavigationBar

Tags: android, android-layout

Возникла проблема с использованием атрибутов:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

В оригинальном *Android* «бары» имеют полупрозрачный градиент (*KitKat*) или полупрозрачный цвет (*Lollipop*).

Но на *Samsung*, *Xiaomi* и, думаю, у ещё нескольких производителей, *StatusBar* прозрачен полностью. В результате чего UI выглядит не круто.

Через *Window* и флаги тоже не работает. [Библиотека SystemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) добавляет *View* под «бары», но хотелось бы стандартной отрисовки.

Причём, в Google Photo белый фон, на котором у таких устройств не видно «баров».

Answer (score 4):

Решение для API 21:

```
Window window = getWindow();
    window.setNavigationBarColor(0x66000000); // (или <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black_40</item>)
    window.setStatusBarColor(0x66000000); // (или <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black_40</item>)
    window
        .getDecorView()
        .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Мы принудительно окрашиваем бары в полупрозрачный чёрный.

Но, соответственно, нужно вычислять размеры отступов для элементов, так как над контентом будет *NavigationBar* и *StatusBar*.